# How to query a specific collection from a RavenDB?

Tags: ravendb

In one database, I am storing two separate documents - CumulativeSprintData and Features. I'm trying to query from javascript. Right now I'm just using the default:

```
http://servername:8080/databases/sprintprogress/indexes/dynamic?
```

The problem is that this default query pulls in documents of both types. How do I specify which document type I want to pull down?

Thanks!

Comment: Note this will only pull back 128 items. If you have lots of sprint data, this approach won't work long term and you will have to revert to paging the data with `?pageSize=128&start=0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
http://servername:8080/databases/sprintprogress/indexes/dynamic/Features

http://servername:8080/databases/sprintprogress/indexes/dynamic/CumulativeSprintDatas
```